# Jailbroken iPhone dead; What firmware "load" options do I have?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I jailbroke my original iPhone first gen to version 3.14 (I think) and since then I'm unable to use the phone.

I've done this before and never once had an issue (so I'm semi-experienced with this).

**Symptoms**

- iTunes says the phone is in recovery mode.

[image]

- The screen looks like a newly loaded (not activated phone)

[image]

**Attempts to fix**

- I've loaded almost every original (not jailbroken) ipsw from 3.0 to the latest one (for this model) and am not able to get back to defaults. I get the following error:
  [image]
- I've loaded many different Jailbreak programs and none of them can make the phone work.

I'm OK if I don't ever get cellular service and just use it as an iPod Touch.  Anyone know how I can get past this screen in either jailbroken or original mode?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you can not use "restore device" ("... when the iphone dows not respond as ecpected ...") in iTunes?

Comment: @Martin - When I restore (see attempts to fix) in iTunes using an original ipsw of almost any version (haven't tried em all) I get error 23

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/jailbroken-iphone-does-not-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I remember well, since 3.1.3 you can't reinstall firmware on jailbreaked phones with itunes. I had the same problem and 3.1.2 restore worked without problem.

needed for iphone 2g:

`BL-39.bin` and `BL-46.bin` boot loaders files

`resdn0w-win_0.9.4` - to jailbreak - other versions were not working with the restore file below

`iPhone1,1_3.1.2_7D11_Restore.ipsw` - restore file worked with itunes 10

I'm sure you can find these files easily for download.

Comment: You can not restore with iTunes and old version of the iOS firmware. You can restore only to the latest one. There are [ways](http://www.saurik.com/id/12) to circumvent this but you should only downgrade/install an old iOS if you have a very good reason to do so. All the latest iOS versions can be [jailbroken](http://greenpois0n.com/).

Comment: you can restore any version if you hold shift key while clicking on restore button and iTunes will ask for the file .ipsw you want to restore (previously downloaded of course). For the latest iOS, yes they can be jailbroken but at least when I did that, there were no way to restore an iOS above 3.1.2 on an already jailbroken non working iphone.

Answer (score 2):

From every piece of literature I can find on the topic, and my own past experience, this normally indicates a hardware failure. Your best bet would be to take it to your nearest Apple store and they might be able to assist.